# Importing package somehow causes shell to crash

Tags: python-3.x, zsh

When I enter the python3 shell in zsh and import a package called pyxtal I see an error:

```
zsh: killed     python3
```

I tried reinstalling this package so far with no luck. How is it even possible that importing a package can crash the program?

Comment: It's not causing the shell to crash.  It's causing the shell to kill your Python process.  I assume from the zsh that you are on a Mac.  Is that right?  The package is large and brings in a lot of pieces.  Perhaps one of them is opening a socket that is blocked in your Mac.